# How to pass an argument to a child method in Javascript OO

Tags: javascript

How do you pass an argument into an inherited method?

```
interactiveElement.prototype.moveTowards = function(target){
     console.log(target);
} 

projectile.prototype.fire = function(target){
    interactiveElement.prototype.moveTowards.call(this); //how do I pass target
}
```

getting error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Just FYI, the code you posted would not generate such an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you must use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), simply pass the argument(s) after the "this" parameter:

```
interactiveElement.prototype.moveTowards.call(this, target); //how do I pass target
```

but if it's actually an inherited method, you can perhaps simplify it:

```
this.moveTowards(target);
```

If `moveTowards` is anywhere in `projectile`s prototype chain, you can access it through `this` instead of using `...prototype...call`.  Where you do have prototypical inheritance, you typically only use `call` to reference a function that is "overloaded by a member lower on the chain," e.g. if `projectile` has a `moveTowards` and `interactiveElement` has a `moveTowards`, and you want to call `ineractiveElement`'s.

Comment: since you said "must use call", is there a better way?

Comment: @wazzaday You were a few seconds ahead of my edit.  :-)

Comment: You might want to note that when used with `call` (or its close cousin, `apply`) a function is not being treated as a method of an object, and the same technique can be used with _any_ function whatsoever.  So for instance, you can do `Date.prototype.setMonth.call(this, 5)` if your object has whatever properties `Date.prototype.setMonth` requires.  It's part of what makes Javascript very different from languages such as Java or C#.

Comment: @ScottSauyet The key difference is the (lack of) a strongly-typed compiler.  Compiled languages will check the type of the `this` parameter and make sure it matches the function signature.  JavaScript doesn't, and assumes that what you pass will provide everything the function expects.  You can have the same mess in C#; but you have to use serialization to do an end run around the strong-type checking.  (Then invoking the function will throw an exception when you pass the wrong `this` in to it, similar to how JavaScript will throw an exception if it can't access the data it tries to.)

Comment: @ScottMermelstein: I actually see this as a positive (at least some days I do), although there is certainly some mess underneath it.  I do more functional than OO programming in JS, so first-class functions and their  features are pretty important to me.